# Laravel Mix - Asset compiler and vendor background image paths

Tags: webpack, laravel-mix

- Laravel Mix Version: 6.0.34 (`npm list --depth=0`)
  ├── @tailwindcss/forms@0.2.1
  ├── @tailwindcss/typography@0.4.1
  ├── @tarekraafat/autocomplete.js@10.2.6
  ├── alpinejs@2.8.2
  ├── autoprefixer@10.3.7
  ├── axios@0.21.4
  ├── flatpickr@4.6.9
  ├── laravel-mix@6.0.34
  ├── lodash@4.17.21
  ├── postcss@8.3.10
  ├── postcss-import@12.0.1
  ├── quill@1.3.7
  ├── resolve-url-loader@4.0.0
  ├── sass@1.43.2
  ├── sass-loader@12.2.0
  ├── tailwindcss@2.2.17
  ├── tinymce@5.10.0
  └── tippy.js@6.3.2
- Node Version (`node -v`):
  v14.17.6
- NPM Version (`npm -v`):
  6.14.15
- OS:
  macOS Big Sur v11.6

#### Description:

I am trying to add 3rd party plugin to my project (Laravel project) `@tarekraafat/autocomplete.js` which has it's own styles with background images. Everything fine, but when I include main plugin style in my style, I get that error message:

```
ERROR in ./resources/css/app.css
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Error: Can't resolve 'images/search.svg' in '/path-to-app/resources/css'
...
1 ERROR in child compilations (Use 'stats.children: true' resp. '--stats-children' for more details)
...
```

Which basically says that `images/search.svg` is not found in vendor folder, where actually image is there. I saw that in target image folder there was created bunch of folders with that image in it, for example: `public/images/vendor/@tarekraafat/autocomplete.js/dist/css/search.svg`.

My `webpack.mix.js`:

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js');
mix.postCss('resources/css/app.css', 'public/css', [
    require('postcss-import'),
    require('tailwindcss'),
    require('autoprefixer'),
]).options({
    processCssUrls: true,
});
mix.sass('resources/scss/main.scss', 'public/css');
```

Any idea?

#### Steps To Reproduce:

1. Import vendor style with `@import '@tarekraafat/autocomplete.js/dist/css/autoComplete.css';` in `resources/css/app.css`
2. Have `processCssUrls: true` option in `webpack.mix.js` (if I set it to `false`, it's all good, but there is no image on the page)
3. Run `npm run prod`

Answer (score 0):

You can put the images in the 'resources' folder where the styles are and use this path inside the css which in this case is /resources/css/app.css.
It will compile and transfer the files that will be in use to the public folder.